# Add child on dynamic component name

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

As I must to add image on several group on the same form, I'd to customize my procédure to do that.

Indeed, actualy, I have something like that,

```
if(value=="17"){
    gv17.addElement(imAc);                                  
    v17.setStyle("backgroundColor",'#ffffff');
}
```

My goal is to do something like that:

```
 if(value=="18"){
        gv18.addElement(imAc);                                  
        v18.setStyle("backgroundColor",'#ffffff');
    }
 if(value=="17"){
        gv17.addElement(imAc);                                  
        v17.setStyle("backgroundColor",'#ffffff');
    }
 if(value=="16"){
        gv16.addElement(imAc);                                  
        v16.setStyle("backgroundColor",'#ffffff');
    }
```

Do you have a solution to solve that.
Indeed, I think it's stupid to write X times (3 in example) to do that. I can refer to object by Name as name is a string.
I'd like to do something like that :

```
var mytarget:string = "gv16";
mytarget.addElement(imAc);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add some additional code or explanation? This would help us better understand your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your objects are named, you might try:

```
this['gv' + value].addElement(imAc);
this['v' + value].setStyle('backgroundColor', '#ffffff');
```

As long as your value number equates to the symbol name numbers, and the logic holds true for every element, this should solve your problem without getting overly complex.